# Using Webpack, upgrading electron app version (Windows) not always removing previous version shortcuts and uninstall entries

Tags: webpack, electron

I have an electron app that I am deploying using webpack. If I install version 2.5.1 and then install version 2.6.2 generally it upgrades as intended (i.e. completely overwrites previous version) but occasionally I am left with version 2.5.1 still showing as an entry in the 'uninstall programs' kust along with the correct 2.6.2 version

package.json:

```
"name": "myapp-desktop",
"productName": "MyApp Desktop",
"description": "MyApp Application",
"version": "2.6.2",
"main": "app/background.js",
"private": true,
"build": {
  "afterSign": "build/afterSignHook.js",
  "appId": "com.mycompany.myappe",
  "buildDependenciesFromSource": true,
  "npmRebuild": false,
  "artifactName": "${productName}-${version}.${ext}",
  "files": [
      "app/**/*",
      "!app/backend",
      "!app/firmware"
    ],
   "publish": null,
   "directories": {
      "buildResources": "build/resources"
    },
   "mac": {
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.plist"
    }
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "preunit": "webpack --config=build/webpack.unit.config.js --env=test --display=none",
    "unit": "electron-mocha temp/specs.js --renderer --require source-map-support/register",
    "pree2e": "webpack --config=build/webpack.development.config.js --env=test --display=none && webpack --config=build/webpack.e2e.config.js --env=test --display=none",
    "e2e": "mocha temp/e2e.js --require source-map-support/register",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "start": "node build/start.js",
    "debug": "node --nolazy --inspect-brk build/start.js",
    "dist": "webpack --config=build/webpack.production.config.js --env=production && electron-builder",
    "release": "npm run test && npm run dist",
    "upgrade-dependencies": "ncu -u && npm install",
    "configure-backend": "node build/configureBackend.js"
  },
```

I thought that having the same appId between versions would cause an upgrade regardless of the version number, what am I missing??